# how to make the javascript null check more clear

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to check a variable in javascript useable:

```
var userName;
if (userName === null 
|| userName === '' 
|| userName === undefined 
|| userName === {}) {
   console.log("useable");
}else{
    console.log("unuseable");
}
```

is there any simple and clear way to do this action? If I use `if(userName){}`, this would not work:

```
var userName='';
if (userName) {
    console.log("null");
}else{
    console.log("not null");
}
```

if I use `Object.keys(obj).length === 0`, this would not work:

```
var obj=new Date();
if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    console.log("null");
}else{
    console.log("not null");
}
```

Comment: Yes. `if (!userName)`.

Comment: `userName === {}` will never be `true`, by the way. Did you mean `Object.keys(userName).length === 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a functional approach, including all of your conditions and checks in the function:

```js
function isNull (value) {
  // any falsy value: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy
  if (!value) return true;
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    // empty array
    if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) return true;
    // empty object
    if (value.toString() === '[object Object]' && JSON.stringify(value) === '{}') return true;
  }
  return false;
}

let username;

if (isNull(username)) {
  console.log('usable');
}
else {
  console.log('not usable');
}
```

Comment: Note that the "empty object" check is contrived for simplicity, and that spec implementations of `JSON.stringify` will throw on circular references, etc. etc.